# MSYS2 on Windows 10 With Glade ( gtk_entry_get_text: assertion 'GTK_IS_ENTRY (entry)' failed )

Tags: c++, c, gcc, gtk3

Unfortunately I'm new to programming in C and I'm experiencing many problems with external libraries compatibility between linux and windows.

I'm trying to learn how to use GTK 3, use Glade to create the interface and geany to write the code in GCC

I'm looking for a solution on the internet for 4 days, but I don't understand how to solve it:

Please be patient, I don't know who to ask by now.
Thanks for your help.

when the "OK" button is pressed.

```
Appair the message on the first gtkentry but the second entry still empty

void gtk_entry_set_text (GtkEntry* otarget, const gchar* TargetText); //Give no action like no command exist
```

Code written in GCC via Geany

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <gmodule.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GtkBuilder      *builder; 
    GtkWidget       *window;
    
    
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    builder = gtk_builder_new();
    gtk_builder_add_from_file (builder, "test.glade", NULL);

    window = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "TestWin"));

    
    
    gtk_builder_connect_signals(builder, NULL);

    g_object_unref(builder);

    gtk_widget_show(window);                
    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}


// I have to put (extern "C" G_MODULE_EXPORT ) because without  give Could not find signal handler 'on_ok_button_clicked'.  Did you compile with -rdynamic?

extern "C" G_MODULE_EXPORT void on_ok_button_clicked(GtkButton *msgbox_ok, GtkEntry *origin, GtkEntry *target, gpointer user_data)
{
        
    
        
        const gchar *OriginText;
        const gchar *TargetText;

        OriginText = gtk_entry_get_text (GTK_ENTRY (origin)); // gtk_entry_get_text: assertion 'GTK_IS_ENTRY (entry)' failed
        
        TargetText = OriginText;
        
        void gtk_entry_set_text (GtkEntry *target, const gchar *TargetText); //Give no action like no command exist


        
    
}
extern "C" G_MODULE_EXPORT void on_cancel_button_clicked(GtkButton *cancel_button, gpointer user_data)
{
    gtk_main_quit();
}
extern "C" G_MODULE_EXPORT void on_TestWin_destroy(GtkWidget *TestWin, gpointer user_data)
{
    
        gtk_main_quit();
}
```

File test.glade in XML creato con Glade 3

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.22.1 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.20"/>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="TestWin">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <property name="default_width">420</property>
    <property name="default_height">200</property>
    <signal name="destroy" handler="on_TestWin_destroy" swapped="no"/>
    <child>
      <placeholder/>
    </child>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkFixed">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkButton" id="ok_button">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">OK</property>
            <property name="width_request">95</property>
            <property name="height_request">35</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives_default">True</property>
            <signal name="clicked" handler="on_ok_button_clicked" swapped="no"/>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="x">190</property>
            <property name="y">130</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkButton" id="cancel_button">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">Cancell</property>
            <property name="width_request">100</property>
            <property name="height_request">35</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives_default">True</property>
            <signal name="clicked" handler="on_cancel_button_clicked" swapped="no"/>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="x">300</property>
            <property name="y">130</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkEntry" id="origin">
            <property name="width_request">300</property>
            <property name="height_request">35</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="x">100</property>
            <property name="y">20</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkEntry" id="target">
            <property name="width_request">300</property>
            <property name="height_request">35</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="x">100</property>
            <property name="y">60</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkLabel" id="lbl_origin">
            <property name="width_request">90</property>
            <property name="height_request">35</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">Origin Text</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="x">5</property>
            <property name="y">20</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkLabel" id="lbl_target">
            <property name="width_request">90</property>
            <property name="height_request">35</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">Target Text</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="x">5</property>
            <property name="y">60</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

Command used for compilation under Windows 10

```
gcc  -pthread -mms-bitfields -IC:/msys64/mingw64/include/gtk-3.0 -IC:/msys64/mingw64/include/cairo -IC:/msys64/mingw64/include -IC:/msys64/mingw64/include/pango-1.0 -IC:/msys64/mingw64/include/fribidi -IC:/msys64/mingw64/include -IC:/msys64/mingw64/include/atk-1.0 -IC:/msys64/mingw64/include/cairo -IC:/msys64/mingw64/include/pixman-1 -IC:/msys64/mingw64/include -IC:/msys64/mingw64/include/freetype2 -IC:/msys64/mingw64/include -IC:/msys64/mingw64/include/harfbuzz -IC:/msys64/mingw64/include/libpng16 -IC:/msys64/mingw64/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -IC:/msys64/mingw64/include -IC:/msys64/mingw64/lib/libffi-3.2.1/include -IC:/msys64/mingw64/include/glib-2.0 -IC:/msys64/mingw64/lib/glib-2.0/include -IC:/msys64/mingw64/include test.cpp -o test -LC:/msys64/mingw64/lib -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -lz -lgdi32 -limm32 -lshell32 -lole32 -Wl,-luuid -lwinmm -ldwmapi -lsetupapi -lcfgmgr32 -lpangowin32-1.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -latk-1.0 -lcairo-gobject -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lintl -lglib-2.0
```

Comment: `extern C` is not the proper way to hook up callbacks.

Comment: I think you need to use `static void` or something. It's been too long...

Comment: @theGtknerd (Without extern C doesn't work and static void doesn't work. Thank you for your suggestion anyway.

Comment: How about plain `void`?

Comment: @theGtknerd // I have to put (extern "C" G_MODULE_EXPORT ) because without  give Could not find signal handler 'on_ok_button_clicked'.  Did you compile with -rdynamic?

Anyway thank you for help, I think is not a good idea use GCC under Windows with GTK ill go back to Visual Studio.

Comment: So have you tried `void on_ok_button_clicked`?

Comment: @theGtknerd  Forgive me if I am not exhaustive in detail, I mistakenly assumed it was clear that specifying in the notes why the use of functions or commands meant having already tried without them.

In any case, yes! I tried Void alone and found unmanageable errors.